# Real-time MMO: how should authoritative server update client position

Tags: networking, mmo, client-server, synchronization, realtime

I'm trying to build a real-time MMO game. I'm using Phaser for FE and Node.js + socket.io for BE. I have read all the tutorials like http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-server-reconciliation.html and so on.

Different players might have different FPS, this is how I update position on the client:

```
const data = {
  down: this.cursors.down.isDown,  
  timestamp: Date.now() 
}; 

var deltaTime = (data.timestamp - this.lastTimestamp) / 1000;
if (data.down) {
    player.position.y += speed * deltaTime;
    socket.emit('input', data);
}
```

This ensures speed is FPS independent (every player is moving with the same speed).

The server is running a tick at 60 FPS. This method is processing saved inputs from players.
**How should the server correct player positions? It doesn't know their delta times.** It can't use server's delta time since it would be always around 0.016 and it doesn't reflect player's update interval.

```
tick() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var serverDelta = (now - this.prevTimestamp) / 1000;
    this.prevTimestamp = now;

    for (var player of players) {
        player.update();
    }
}

player.update() {
    for (input in savedInputs) {
          player.y += input.down * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered decoupling your game simulation step from your rendering framerate? (a la "[Fix Your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)")  There's no particular reason the server should need to care about rendering details.

Comment: Server is definitely not caring about rendering. The question is how the server reach same same result as client (on player y position)